# ¿Como cambiar tabs en materialize sin utilizar JQuery?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

Quiero cambiar de tabs pero sin utilizar JQuery, he instanciado los elementos utilizando M.AutoInit(); lo que quiero utilizar seria algo similar a esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
});
```

pero sin utilizar JQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para lograr la navegación entre *tabs* y no depender del uso de JQuery entonces primero vamos a recuperar la etiqueta de la lista desordenada a través de la clase que tiene asignada de este modo:

```
let tabs = document.querySelector(".tabs")
```

El método `document.querySelector()` nos permite recuperar el nodo que le indiquemos sea por su nombre, por su id o por la clase que tiene asignada.

Basándonos en la documentación entonces pasamos como primer argumento a la instancia la variable en la cual almacenamos el método anteriormente descrito.

```
let instance = M.Tabs.init(tabs);
```

**Ejemplo completo tomado de la documentación <sup>1</sup>**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
        <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
        <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
        <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let tabs = document.querySelector(".tabs")
        var instance = M.Tabs.init(tabs);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Referencia**

- <sup>1</sup> [tab system](https://materializecss.com/tabs.html)

Comment: Hola Aprendiz, tu respuesta es útil. Lo único que tienes que reemplazar es `query.selector()` por `querySelector()`. Estoy seguro que se trató de un error tipográfico.